# rxjs, how to get latest data with two triggers and know who was triggered?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmano3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
<button (click)="trigger1.next()">Button 1</button>
<button (click)="trigger2.next(false)">Button 2</button>

{{ myObservable$ | async }}
```

---

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  trigger1 = new Subject<void>();
  trigger2 = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  data$ = of('some data');

  myObservable$ = new Observable<number>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservable$ = someMagicOerator([data$, trigger1, trigger2]).pipe(
      map(
        ([
          latestData,
          isTrigger1Triggered,
          isTrigger2TriggeredWithBoolData
        ]) => {
          if (isTrigger1Triggered) {
            //I want to access here latesData from data$
            console.log(latestData);
            return 1;
          } else if (isTrigger2Triggered) {
            //I want to access here latesData from data$
            //and access trigger2 boolean data
            console.log(latestData);
            console.log(trigger2BooleanData);
            return 2;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get result **1** when pressing **button 1**, and get result **2** when pressing **button 2**. And its needed to access latest data from data$ and data from triger2 in both casses.
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> access latest data from data$ and trigger2

sounds much like `combineLatest` to me, but not sure if it's caching behavior is what you are looking for.

Maybe you also need to split up your Observable into two Observables so that you can distinguish the two button clicks:

```
this.myObservable$ = merge(
  combineLatest([data$, trigger1]).pipe(
    map(([latestData]) => {
      // access latestData here;
      return 1;
    })
  ),
  combineLatest([data$, trigger2]).pipe(
    map(([latestData, booleanValue]) => {
      // access latestData and booleanValue here;
      return 2;
    })
  )
);
```

I'm using `merge` to combine both Observables back into one for the user of `this.myObservable$`.